# Outlook to PDF language character conversion errors

Tags: windows-8.1, microsoft-outlook-2010, adobe-acrobat, character-encoding

I have Adobe Acrobat dc trial and Windows 8.1.

When I try to `Convert to Adobe PDF` an email with Greek characters from Outlook 2010, some of the Greek characters get changed to Latin.

[image]

> RIGHT TEXT BEFORE CONVERSION ->  Καλημέρα **παιδιά τι κάνετε**
>
> WRONG TEXT AFTER CONVERSION   ->  Κaληµέρa **paιdιά tι κάνete**

In the conversion there are present Greek and Latin characters together.

Comment: sorry about this but your question is?

Comment: Why when i try to Convert to Adobe PDF an email with Greek characters from Outlook 2010, English and Greek characters confuses?

Answer (score 0):

### Unicode, charset and font mix problems.

It seems that you have some problem with a **mix** of unicode/charset/font in the original document.

The Greek characters are not in the first 127 position of the ascii table.
Following the ***Unicode*** standard <sup>[[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode)]</sup> you should find them in the range [`0370-03FF`](http://unicode-table.com/en/#greek-coptic) <sup>[[2](http://unicode-table.com/en/#greek-coptic)]</sup>. For example the letter alpha is the unicode `U+03B1` <sup>[[3](http://unicode-table.com/en/03B1/)]</sup>.  As references it follows the ISO/IEC_8859-7 standard<sup>[[4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-7)]</sup> called Windows-28597 from the Microsoft.

The problem is that it exists even a font (or more than one) that writes the `a` as an `α`, keeping inside the same internal code (the 97). For example **Symbol** is one of the four standard fonts available on all PostScript-based printers (and so in the latex documents and in the pdf ones), created by adobe and has an internal representation different from the unicode one <sup>[[5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbol_(typeface)#Font_comparison)]</sup>:

```
Symbol    α     β   γ   δ   ε   ζ   η   θ   ι   κ   λ   μ 
Symbol*   a     b   g   d   e   z   h   q   i   k   l   m
Symbol    ν     ξ   ο   π   ρ   ς   σ   τ   υ   φ   χ   ψ   ω
Symbol*   n     x   o   p   r   V   s   t   u   f   c   y   w
*encoded as ASCII for older versions of the font
```

<sup>See the rendering with different fonts on the [this wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbol_(typeface)#Font_comparison).</sup>

This font however, contains only the complete unaccented Greek alphabet. So it can happens when in a document there is a mix of different fonts and charsets that in the *translation* something goes lost and you end up with an hybrid representation.

**Further references**

- The *amazing zoo* of the [*Character encoding*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding) <sup>[[6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding)]</sup>.
- [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) <sup>[[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode)]</sup> page on wiki.
- A [table](http://unicode-table.com/en/#greek-coptic) <sup>[[2](http://unicode-table.com/en/#greek-coptic)]</sup> of rendered *unicode* ranges.
- The [ISO/IEC_8859-7 standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-7) <sup>[[4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-7)]</sup>
- Just in case you didn't feel it enough complicated there were different codepages too:
  [codepage 737](http://www.ascii-codes.com/cp737.html) or the less common [codepage 869](http://www.ascii-codes.com/cp869.html).